# .htaccess RewriteRule outputs wrong parameter result

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to use .htaccess RewriteRule to beautify some urls, but I've got a problem that I can't fix. 
I've written this:

```
 RewriteEngine On

 RewriteRule ^(.*)/(foro|forum)$  code/forum/forum.php?id=$1
 RewriteRule ^(.*)/(foro|forum)/(.*)$  code/forum/forum.php?id=$1&subf=$3
 RewriteRule ^(.*)/(foro|forum)/(.*)/(.*)$  code/forum/forum.php?id=$1&subf=$3&post=$4
```

The first url rewrite works properly, showing as result the id parameter (I.e. localhost/web/user501/forum -> id=user501).
It happens the same with the second one (localhost/web/user501/forum/3 -> id=user501, subf=3).

But when I try the third url rewrite, somehow the output id is not 'user501' as I expect, but 'code/forum/forum.php'.
The output of the other vars is normal (localhost/web/user501/forum/3/5 -> id=code/forum/forum.php, subf=3, post=5).

I tried to change the first (.*) on that url rewrite for a fixed word... it worked, but unfortunately I need it to be a changeful word.

Does someone know what's happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because `^(.*)/(foro|forum)/(.*)/(.*)$` pattern also matches `code/forum/forum.php` hence `RewriteRule` runs again and gives you wrote results.

Try this code:

```
RewriteEngine On

# ignore /code/forum/forum.php
RewriteRule ^code/forum/forum\.php$ - [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(foro|forum)$ code/forum/forum.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(foro|forum)/(.*)$ code/forum/forum.php?id=$1&subf=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(foro|forum)/(.*)/(.*)$ code/forum/forum.php?id=$1&subf=$3&post=$4 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't get that strange id anymore, now I understand my mistake.